# Float number in base of logarithmic function. It is not possible?

Tags: ubuntu, math, calculator

I can't understand, why any calculators don't allow me to write float number base of logarithmic functions. For example: `log 1,024(2000)`. Here I want to know what the exponent of `1,024` should be to get `2000`.

I have poor math knowledges. Can anybody explain what do I wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can use the identity `log_a(b) == log(b) / log(a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use log 2000 / log 1,024 instead.